# Python django django-crontab only runs once. How can I test it running the expected every minute?

Tags: python, django, cron

I have installed [django-crontab](https://github.com/kraiz/django-crontab) to the python virtual environment. I am attempting to add a row to a Google sheet daily, I know the function works so I just need a cron job to trigger it.

```
python 3.6.7
django 2.0.9
django-crontab 7.0.1
```

Below is my folder structure:

```
├── api
│   ├── utils
│   |    └── cron.py
|---manage.py
```

Here is my cron.py

```
# For Google API to sheets
import pygsheets

# The ID of spreadsheet.
SPREADSHEET_ID = 'abc123'

def addToGraphs():
    # Use service credentials 
    print('Attempt CRON')
    gs = pygsheets.authorize(service_account_file='credentials.json')
    spreadsheet = gs.open_by_key(SPREADSHEET_ID)
    graphsWorksheet = spreadsheet.worksheet_by_title('Graphs')
    graphsWorksheet.append_table(["29/12/2020", 1, 2, 3])
    return True
```

In my settings.py I have added CRONJOBS like so:

```
CRONJOBS = [
    ('*/1 * * * *', 'utils.cron.addToGraphs')
]
```

Using the commands that the documentation says, I am seemingly correctly adding the cron using:
`python manage.py crontab add .`

And then able to list that correctly using:
`python manage.py crontab show`

When I run it locally using:
`python manage.py crontab run {taskId}`

The function does print out "Attempt CRON" and adds the row to the Google sheet, yay! But only once... It then just ends.

When I kick off the python django server with:
`python manage.py runserver`

I get no print statement and the Google doc doesn't update.

What am I missing? I feel I am close as when I run it manually it works. Any advice is appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Write CRONJOBS in end of the setting files and also its python manage.py crontab add without dot in the end.

Comment: CRONJOBS is at the end of the settings file and I have attempted adding cron without the dot. Same result

Comment: try to add full path in CRONJOBS might help you like  api.utils.cron.addToGraphs

Comment: When I put the full path we can't find the module:
"ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'api'"

Answer (score 0):

Relative paths didn't work I had to update the path to my credentials.json file to an absolute path.
I changed:
`credentails.json`
to
`/Users/Matt/Documents/Project/Backend/api/credentials.json`